# Implementing String Interpolation Using Expression Trees?

Tags: replace, expression-trees, string-parsing, string-interpolation

I am working on an application that needs to support user-configurable strings, kind of like how string interpolation works in C# 6. For example, the app should accept a string like the following:

```
"<%Variable1%>-<%Variable2%>-StaticTextHere_<%Text(<%DateTime(MMdd(yyyy)hhmmssfff)%>_<%Variable3%>_HardCoded)%>"
```

And do search-and-replace substitutions, using a Dictionary that has the keys to do so. So *<%Variable1%>* would be basically replaced with *theDictionary["Variable1"]*. A <%DateTime(format)%> tag would be treated just like the .NET implementation works. So in my example, *<%DateTime(MMdd(yyyy)hhmmssfff)%>* would be something like *1005(2016)09502046* for right now.

A twist is that anything inside the <%Text()%> tags should be treated as static, hard-coded text and just "ignored." Otherwise, in my example above, that <%DateTime%> tag would be computed. Instead, the resulting string would still have that <%DateTime(MMdd(yyyy)hhmmssfff)%> part in it (<%Text%> tag removed), after the search-and-replace is done (the idea being some other downstream app will pick it up, parse it, and compute it or do a search-and-replace on it.

My question is this: What would you use to write the logic that parses and computes this functionality? My co-worker and I were tossing around ideas and were probably going to do it by splitting the input string on the beginning and/or end tags (<% or %>) but I remembered something similar I did in college and after looking at my old code, realized I wrote a little app that takes a logical expression, builds an expression tree, and prints out and evals the expression tree.

**So it seemed like this string parsing problem could be solved using expression trees. Do you guys agree? What what you guys use or create to parse a string like the one I have above and do a search-and-replace on the proper fields** (leaving any <%Text(Something)%> fields to just be equal to "Something")**?**

Comment: Expression trees could be used simply,  If you are making (certain) functions callable al la DateTime I would just make Text() a function of that returns its input, thus you only have 2 things to cope with <%Variable1%> and <%NAME(stuff)%>.  What is not clear is if nesting is allowed? ie DateTime(Variable1) or DateTime(OffsetDays(Now(),3)) type things?  If nesting _isn't_ allowed are ExpressionTrees are worth it (its a very shallow tree).  If you nest, expression trees are the way to go BUT you need to think about your grammar, eg DateTime(MMdd(yyyy)) could be a nested call OR a literal.

Comment: Perhaps a better way of putting it is that Expression trees are probably what you want to parse _into_ but you still need to actually PARSE via some method.